# Use a folder in a SharePoint Slideshow

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm creating a website with SharePoint online and I want to use a slideshow whipped in my page. 
I've always used this application with pics libraries, but today I should use it with folders in my library.
I have a list with articles and when a user creates a new article, a little workflow creates a new folder in the pic library where the user can save the pics of the article. So I need to create a page for all the article and so, use only the specific folder on the slideshow. 
I need your help! Thanks

Comment: You could use JSOM or REST programming to read SharePoint data, or you could use a Content Query WebPart and some XSLT, or you could use DisplayTemplates or you could write (ClientSideRedering) CSR code and attach a JSLink or you could use the Modern SharePoint framework.. In all cases you need some decent JavaScript programming skills